# Mongodb index on timestamp vs ISO 8601 datetime string

Tags: mongodb

I need a best practice for a new mongo db I create.

I have one time field in the documents to be saved.
Because this field will get queried a lot, I want to create an index on it.

What is the best practice for the format of indexed time fields?
Should I go for a unix timestamp or an string in ISO 8601 format like *2009-01-01T12:00:00+01:00*?

Comment: You should **always** prefer the native data type, so `Date` in your case. Using strings will sooner or later result in problems.

Comment: but a `Date` can be represented in JSON in different ways, as a human readable `String` or as a number (unix timestamp). I would say a ISO 8601 `String` is the way to write dates in JSON. But I wonder if a index on a number (unix timestamp) would not be more efficient than indexing the longer `String` representation in case of excessive querying.

Comment: No, there is only one `Date` object. The **internal** value is a number (milliseconds from `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. The **displayed** value actually can be anything and depends on your client. Thus index on `Date` is an index on an integer value which should be very efficient.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but I thought there is no such thing as a Date object in JSON. How does the database know the value to a field is a date?
What format does the JSON value have to be that the mongo db knows this field should be saved as a date?

Comment: JSON is purely text (plus `null`, boolean and numbers) - that's correct. However, MongoDB stores `BSON` documents. In BSON the elements are not just strings, see [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/). BSON is an extension of JSON.